# Multiple capture groups in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string that either has a number or the letter `a`, possibly followed by`r` or `l`.

In MATLAB the following regexp returns as

```
>> regexp('10r', '([0-9]*|a)(l|r)*', 'match')
ans = 
    '10r'
```

I would expect `10` and `r` separately, because I have two capture groups. Is there a way to get a cell array with both returned independently? I can't see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want 'tokens' instead of 'match'

```
>> toks = regexp('10r', '([0-9]*|a)(l|r)*', 'tokens');
>> toks{1}
ans = 
    '10'    'r'
```

Or if you want to get fancy, name the tokens and get a struct array:

```
>> toks = regexp('10r', '(?<number>[0-9]*|a)(?<letter>l|r)*', 'names');
>> toks
toks = 
    number: '10'
    letter: 'r'
```

Comment: Perfect! The second example is great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match

> either has a number or the letter a, possibly followed by **r** or **l** as the `*` means 0 or more times.

You can also use [0-9]+ to match at least a single number and use a character class to match either r or l.

```
([0-9]+|a)([lr]?)
```

The pattern matches:

- `([0-9]+|a)` Capture **group 1**, match either 1+ digits 0-9 or match `a`
- `([lr])?` Capture **group 2**, optionally match either `l` or `r`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZGjkMg/1)

To prevent partial matches, you could also use word boundaries:

```
\<([0-9]+|a)([lr]?)\>
```