# regex for json key value

Tags: json, regex, matlab

Hi i'm new to regex and i'm trying to grab the value after `l_fix` in the following json:

```
{ "id": "626307" ,"t" : ".INX" ,"e" : "INDEXSP" ,"l" : "2,050.59" ,"l_fix" : "2050.59" ,"l_cur" : "2,050.59" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"3:08PM EST" ,"lt" : "Nov 17, 3:08PM EST" ,"lt_dts" : "2015-11-17T15:08:33Z" ,"c" : "-2.60" ,"c_fix" : "-2.60" ,"cp" : "-0.13" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.13" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "2053.19" }
```

right now i'm using `\d[,](?:\d*\.)?\d+`
however this seems a bit brute force and i'm sure it can be done better.

Comment: It hardly thepends on witch character are admittend inside the "property names" and in "values"

Comment: Language? JavaScript I suppose. Why a regex?

Comment: ***Decode*** the JSON into whatever native array/object type your language of choice has and simply access the key...!?

Comment: See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/7QzW8l) (just to show how easy it is with a JSON parser).

Comment: I agree with @deceze. Parsing the json with a fitting library (depends on the language you're working in) is the proper way to do this.

Comment: You're probably asking the wrong question. You're trying to deal with a string of JSON? As @deceze mentions, your best bet is probably to parse the JSON string, and then just access the value by key.

Comment: i'm using matlab and the json parser is slow.  since i always only want the value after `l_fix` i figure a regex would be a faster way to grab the data i want.

Comment: → http://stackoverflow.com/q/26420725/476?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex doesn't seem to be what you need, however if you want to do it with a regex it could be this one: `"l_fix"\s*:\s*"(.+?)"`. Then, in the first group you'll have the value you are looking for.

[See it working here](http://regexr.com/3c850)

Also, [see this SO post about regex groups in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574550/310276).

Comment: I had tried this also but i only want to return the number after `l_fix` and not the key itself.  I thought that `?:` would do the trick but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: See the SO post I linked. You need `'tokens'` instead of `'match'`

Answer (score -3):

Why regex, best way using JSON parser.
Example in JavaScript:

```
var str = '{ "id": "626307" ,"t" : ".INX" ,"e" : "INDEXSP" ,"l" : "2,050.59" ,"l_fix" : "2050.59" ,"l_cur" : "2,050.59" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"3:08PM EST" ,"lt" : "Nov 17, 3:08PM EST" ,"lt_dts" : "2015-11-17T15:08:33Z" ,"c" : "-2.60" ,"c_fix" : "-2.60" ,"cp" : "-0.13" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.13" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "2053.19" }';
var parsedStr = JSON.parse(str);
alert(parsedStr.l_fix);
```

Other languages also has JSON parser.

Comment: bad answer; in my case I'm trying to parse log files. I don't want to load up each line of the log, parse the JSON and then find the data I need, it's time-consuming and memory intensive to do that. Using a regex seems possible to do and it is *faster* and uses *less memory*.

Comment: "Log file case" it is your case. In this question does not means log file